# how to set and test nginx uwsgi_buffer_size

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi, test

I have a nginx+uwsgi setup to deploy a django app. I noticed that when using g+ authentication the response from the django app has a dimention that is growing month after month. I'm reading the uwsgi logs and particularly the end of the line:

```
7 headers in 795 bytes
6 headers in 16145 bytes
```

Now the average is around 10k but every now and then it goes under 4k. When it's over 4k it returns 502 (Bad Gateway).

To debug it I'd like to analyze what's the content of such a huge header but I need to make nginx accept those headers w/o raising:

```
upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream
```

I set the nginx conf as this:

```
    location /accounts {
       uwsgi_pass mystaff;
       uwsgi_buffer_size 32k;
       uwsgi_buffers 32 32k;
       uwsgi_busy_buffers_size   128k;
       ...
   }
```

But it seems that nothing changes. I still have that error if the header dimension if greater than 4k.
How can I set nginx to accept such a great header and test it: is it possible to dump the configuration?